# Unable to get stateparams in resolve while opening modal in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wanted to open a modal for detail view of particular user when clicked on view detail link.But I don't get the id of user in resolve attribute of $uibModal.open().But that id is available in inline controller function

```
.state('dashboard.users',{
    url:'/users',
    cache:false,
    views:{
        'listusers':{templateUrl:'./partials/users/list.tpl.html?time='+ Math.random(),controller:'UsersController'}
    },
    authenticate:true
})
 .state('dashboard.users.view',{
        url:'/view/:id',
        parent:'dashboard.users',
        cache:false,
        authenticate:true,
        onEnter:['$uibModal',function ($uibModal) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl:'./partials/users/view.tpl.html',
                keyboard:false,backdrop:'static',
                size:'sm',
                resolve:{
                    userData: function($stateParams, $state) {
                         console.log($stateParams.id);// unable to get id
                    }
                },
                controller:function($scope,$uibModalInstance,$state,UsersFactory,userData,$stateParams){
                    $scope.closeLoginModal=function(){
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        $state.go('dashboard.users');
                    }
                  console.log($stateParams.id); // id is avaliable over here
                }
            });
        }]
    });
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in users">
    <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.website }}</td>
    <td><a ui-sref="dashboard.users.view({id:i.id})"><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">View</button></a></td>
</tr>
```

Am I doing something wrong .Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Several things, but to answer your question first. onEnter's callbacks **do** have access to the resolves of the state. But in your code, you have the resolves -inside- the callback, which won't work. Move the resolves to the state declaration, where they should be.

You also have a controller inside the callback, it won't work either. Again, controller declaration needs moving to the state, and IMHO, needs moving to an entirely separate file (avoids clogging up the config.routes which you don't need, and this also makes unit testing a lot easier).

It's nice that you're using onEnter but it's rare to see it. I would move all your modal functionality into the controller (a separate file as I mentioned), and trigger it from the controller's constructor.

Comment: I want to use stateful modal thats why I need to use onEnter function with resolve but I would appreciate if there is any proper way avaliable.Also I accept controller defination should not be inline.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem was I injected $stateParams in OnEnter function below is sample code

```
   onEnter:['$uibModal','$stateParams',function ($uibModal,$stateParams) {
            var id = $stateParams.id;
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl:'./partials/users/view.tpl.html',
                keyboard:false,backdrop:'static',
                size:'sm',
                resolve:{
                    userData: function($state) {
                         console.log(id); // id avaliable
                    }
                },
                controller:function($scope,$uibModalInstance,$state,UsersFactory,userData,$stateParams){
                    $scope.closeLoginModal=function(){
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        $state.go('dashboard.users');
                    }
                    console.log($stateParams);
                }
            });
        }]
```